# How to prevent hibernation during work hours

Tags: windows-7, power-management, hibernate

I have a laptop at work that I don't want it to hibernate during work hours. It may be running a program that will corrupt the current data if it hibernates. After work, it can hibernate until someone needs it the next work day.

Is there a configuration that will allow this, or do I have to exchange 2 power settings?

Comment: You might be able to do this with scheduled tasks, schedule a task to run every couple of minutes until a certain time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POWERCFG -X <SETTING> <VALUE>

<SETTING>   Specifies one of the following options:
            -monitor-timeout-ac <minutes>
            -monitor-timeout-dc <minutes>
            -disk-timeout-ac <minutes>
            -disk-timeout-dc <minutes>
            -standby-timeout-ac <minutes>
            -standby-timeout-dc <minutes>
            -hibernate-timeout-ac <minutes>
            -hibernate-timeout-dc <minutes>
```

Create two scheduled tasks that call PowerCfg to disable and enable standby/hibernation at the beginning and end of your shift respectively. (Setting *minutes* to 0 is the same as setting it to *Never* via `Control Panel\Power Options\Change Plan Settings`.)